# Don't have audio or video symbols on my Facetime

Tags: facebook

I am a first-time user of Facetime.  My Facetime are activated but I can't make avideo or audio call.  The video or audio symbols are not available.  I goto Facetime setting and couln't sign in the account to view the account.  Message was"Unabe to contact the Facetime server".

What's wrong ?

My connection to the web is OK, my wife's Ipad facetime is functioning OK.

I still can't call on Facetime.

Answer (score 1):

This Knowledge Base article from apple should help you. I believe the following section from the article should resolve your issue.

> Wi-Fi network issues
>
> - If you encounter issues using a Wi-Fi network, use standard Wi-Fi network troubleshooting to resolve interference and other issues.
> - If you are using router, firewall, or security software that restricts Internet access, verify that the ports documented in Using
>     FaceTime behind a Firewall are open.
> - FaceTime requires a broadband connection. Performance may vary according to network throughput and usage.

Read more of this Knowledge Base article - http://support.apple.com/ts3367